# selenium - Finding elements returned an unexpected error

Tags: python, windows, selenium, internet-explorer-6

Using Ie driver with Selenium Python bindings, I get the following exception:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Finding elements returned an unexpected error
'
```

However, I get no exception on Linux+Chrome.

What does this message refer to? The trackback does not seem to be helpful at all.

The code used to find the element:

```
self.element_by_id(input_id).send_keys(value)
```

Comment: show the code,which you used,to find the element.

Comment: ok, I've posted an edit.

Comment: probably the element is hidden,if you provide the wright id although.Show the relevant html part.

Comment: The element is displayed. This code is working well in other browsers. Additionally, after testing a few cases with a couple different websites, all find_element_by_* methods return the same exceptions. Like finding "input" elements on google.com fails as well.

Comment: Sounds like a timing issue (tries to access the element before the page DOM is ready). Without relevant code it is impossible to give definite answer what could cause this.

Comment: I don't think it's a timing issue. Or at least I suppose, it is not a timing issue in my code. If I run this code: `ie = webdriver.Ie()` and `ie.get("http://google.com")` then I'm still unable to find any element with any method, even after waiting a couple seconds. For instance, `ie.find_elements_by_css_selector("*, input")` returns the same exception.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, someone on my team is having the same issue. Definitely not a timing issue, we can visually see the element, the page source has the element immediately prior to trying to find the element, but fetching it yields the same "unexpected error" problem.